# Why does the plot of the legendre symbol of $x^2 - y^2$ over a finite field look rectangular

Tags: graphing-functions, finite-fields, quadratic-forms, quadratic-residues

[image]

The small top-left thing is a plot of the legendre symbol of $x^2 - y^2$ over $\Bbb F_{37}$. The thing in the middle is plot for $\Bbb F_{587}$. The thing on the right is a plot of the legendre symbol of $xy$ over $\Bbb F_{587}$.

Question is, why do they ($\left(\dfrac{x^2 - y^2}{587} \right)$ and $\left(\dfrac{xy}{587} \right)$) look rectangular?

The following are plots of the same without the Legendre symbol. Notice how they don't look so rectangular.

[image]

Cheers.

---

I *have* noticed that $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$ which could explain the similarity between the plots. But that's not enough to explain why the plot of $\left(\dfrac{xy}{587} \right)$ looks rectangular.

Also, the middle thing in the following picture is a plot of $x^2 + y^2$

[image]

and now we take the legendre symbols

[image]

For $x^2 + y^2$ it looks noisy and non-rectangular.

---

In response to Jyrki's question, the thing on the right is over $\Bbb F_{593}$

[image]

More examples of Legendre symbols of $x^2 + y^2$ where $-1$ is a quadratic residue:
[image]
Left is mod 53. Middle is mod 41. Right is mod 37.

Comment: The range of the first function is $\{0,\pm1\}$ and without the Legendre symbol the range is the field itself. How are these color coded? What do you mean be "rectangular" anyway?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I just use black if it's a nonresidue and white if it is. Can't you see the rectangularity-ishness of it? Especially of the quad-residue map of $xy$.

Comment: Some of the extra symmetries can be explained by the fact that modulo $37$ there exists a square root of $-1$. This adds some reflective symmetries.

Comment: I figured out the black/grey/white part, but how do you color code $x^2-y^2$ modulo $587$ WITHOUT Legendre?

Comment: the legendre symbol of that is my display picture

Comment: 0 maps to black and 586 to white.

Comment: I guess what you are seeing is a consequence of two things: 1) Legendre symbol is multiplicative, so $\chi(xy)=\chi(x)\chi(y)$ and $\chi(x^2-y^2)=\chi(x+y)\chi(x-y)$. 2) There are intervals where the density of quadratic residues or NQRs is higher than average. When $(x,y)$ (resp. $(x+y,x-y)$) range over such intervals, you get a nearly monochromatic region in the top right (resp. top middle) plot.

Comment: When you leave out the crude quantization introduced by the Legendre symbol, the changes in greylevel become more gradual.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen please take a look

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the noisiness of the $x^2+y^2$ plot comes from the fact that this quadratic form does not factor, $\left(\frac{-1}{587}\right)=-1$. Modulo $593$ (or any prime $\equiv1\pmod4$) the form $x^2+y^2$ does factor, so you may, again, get rectangles. The awkward slopes may ruin that though. Please try!

Comment: Ok. Didn't work out :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen added some more

Comment: Interesting! Looks like there are some kind of shapes, when $-1$ is a QR, but they aren't rectangular.

Comment: Try looking at the graph of $f(x)f(y)$ and $f(x+y)f(x-y)$ for other functions $f$ with sparse range but not-too-sparse support. See if rectangularity appears.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what the univariate Legendre symbols $\chi(x)$ modulo 587 looks like. Along the $x$-axis there is a black square at the QRs and the rest is white.[image]

You see that there are largely white bands and largely black bands. When you plot $\chi(xy)=\chi(x)\chi(y)$ those bands become (nearly) monochromatic regions in the 2D-plot. Because $\chi(x^2-y^2)=\chi(x-y)(x+y)$ you get the same nearly monochromatic regions but rotated by 45 degrees, because this time the factors are constant along lines with slopes $\pm1$.

---

<strike>Because $-1$ is a NQR modulo $587$ we cannot write the form $x^2+y^2$ as a product of two linear forms. Therefore this regions do not appear when plotting $\chi(x^2+y^2)$ modulo $587$.</strike>

**A suggestion:** Modulo $p=593$ we do have that $-1$ is a quadratic residue as $77^2\equiv-1\pmod{593}$. Therefore
$$x^2+y^2\equiv (x+77y)(x-77y)\pmod{593}.$$
Will those nearly monochromatic regions reapper, if you plot $\chi(x^2+y^2)$ modulo $593$? That $77$ may be too awkward a slope to show up :-)

---

When you leave out the Legendre symbol, the changes become more gradual. That may be all you need to remove those rectangles.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to think more about this :-(

Comment: i've added the picture to the end of the post

Comment: I think the first part of your answer has something to it.

Comment: Yeah. But  I will scratch the stuff Re: $-1$ being a QR.

Comment: The imaginary units mod 593 are ±77. As 77's not small relative to 593, the graph of y=77x mod 593 will trace out near-vertical lines for narrow bands of x intervals and jump from line to line. (One may type `plot y=Mod[77x,593] from x=0 to 592` into wolfram alpha to see.)